# Como fazer buscas avançadas no GitHub?

Tags: github

É possível construir operadores/queries personalizados na busca do GitHub?

O GitHub fornece a [busca avançada](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) através de um [GUI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_gr%C3%A1fica_do_utilizador), mas alem disso, como existem as buscas [avançadas do Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en) (site:, cache:, etc...), é possivel fazer o mesmo buscando arquivos e diretórios específicos?

Isso com certeza pode ser útil para qualquer desenvolvedor, tomando como exemplo códigos de terceiros de acordo com sua busca personalizada.

Comment: https://github.com/search/advanced aqui você vai encontrar todas as opções de pesquisa disponíveis.

Comment: Sim, porem não através da busca por parâmetros. Estou vendo como fica mais rápido efetivar buscas através dos "operadores".

Comment: Na real, tenta digitar qualquer coisa em qualquer campo desse link que eu te passei que vai aparecer o que você quer no campo da pesquisa ;)

Comment: Sim, ele adiciona os operadores comuns, mas não os avançados como `filename:` e `filepath:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todas pesquisas *inline* que você pode fazer:

- `user`
- `repo`
- `created`
- `language`
- `stars`
- `forks`
- `size`
- `pushed`
- `fork`
- `extension`
- `size`
- `path`
- `state`
- `comments`
- `label`
- `author`
- `mentions`
- `assignee`
- `updated`
- `fullname`
- `location`
- `followers`
- `repos`
- `updated`
- `fork`

Answer (score 2):

Depois de alguma pesquisa encontrei como isso pode ser feito.

É possível buscar por arquivos específicos, datas, diretórios, entre diversas outras formas de busca. Veja abaixo alguns exemplos:

```
filepath:app/models filename:user.rb
```

O `filepath` irá buscar pelo caminho exato em todos os projetos hospedados publicamente no GitHub. E o `filename` pelo nome do arquivo.

Encontre mais informações sobre buscas avançadas [search-syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/) e [searching-code](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/).